# Javascript error 80004005 in my HTA Application

Tags: javascript, html, hta

```
function getWindowsUserName()
{
    var WinNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
    var urlToSite = createCustomURL(WinNetwork.UserName);
    document.getElementById("psyncLink").src = urlToSite;       
    if(requestingPassword())
    {
        alert("password button screen");
    } else {
        alert("direct password required");
    }
}

function requestingPassword()
{       // <-- This is the line that is getting the error
                          // Unspecified error
                          // Code: 80004005
                          // Microsoft JScript Runtime error
    var btn = window.frames[1].document.getElementsByName("SUBMIT-password.pss");
    if (btn.length == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I wanted requestingPassword to be a bool method but then i learned that Javascript doesn;t support method names like

```
public bool nameofmethod()
```

I think the syntax is correct. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requestingPassword()` is called **immediately** after setting the URL of a frame. It's extremely likely that the page did not finish loading when the `frames[1].document.....` method was called. In that case, `frames[1].document` is `null`, which causes an error to be thrown.

To fix this problem, simply call the `requestingPassword` function in an `onload` event.

```
var frame = document.getElementById("psyncLink");
frame.onload = function() {
    frame.onload = null;
    if (requestingPassword()) {
        alert("password button screen");
    } else {
        alert("direct password required");
    }
};
frame.src = urlToSite;
```

- Note 1: Instead of referring the frame by `window.frames[1]` (which is not easy to maintain), use `frame.contentWindow` (which is supported extremely well, and does not depend on knowledge of the frame's position)
- Note 2: Setting `onload` as a property will not bind an event in IE6-. If you have to support IE6, use `.attachEvent("onload", func..);`.

Comment: Is there another way to do this without frame.onload

Comment: @CocoaDev No, because you **have to** wait for the frame to be loaded. The alternative solution must be synchronous, which means that something has to block the execution of your code. That's not possible, and certainly a bad option. PS. You must have encountered a huge problem with my answer, since you've unaccepted, unupvoted and downvoted it. Can you explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: The issue is that the code is always executed. I placed the frame.onload code in a function and I need the second frame to finish processing before the site loads with the frame.onload

Comment: "The code is always executed" - Well, there are no syntax errors, so that's the expected behaviour (on a serious note: What did you expect, and what did not happen?). And what's with the last sentence: Is it an observation, or an unfulfilled desire?